# Why are there so many different base64 implementations?

Tags: java, base64

I want to use base64 in java, and after google, I found so many libraries provide their own base64 util, e.g. hadoop, apache codec, apache dbutil. And java doesn't have one, there's just  one base64 util resides in sun.misc, it's a vendor-related api for sun(oracle).

Why there's so many choices?

Comment: The question "why..." is valid here and interesting for a beginner; the question "which to choose" is causing this question to be "closed" - consider removing that.

Comment: why would you vote to close a valid question with a valid answer an hour later? SO bureaucrats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using sun.* is always a bad idea since your code will break if run on any other jvm (there are jvms out there made by ibm and others that dont have any sun.* classes).

most libraries who roll their own do this because they dont want to incur dependencies and because base64 encoding isnt that hard to do.

just pick an external library (ideally the smallest one, with the least amount of dependencies) and use it. personally i'd take [apache commons codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/), because base64 is one of the libraries' main purposes, instead of going for some other library thats intended to do something completely different and just happens to have base64

Answer (score 0):

> So which one should I choose?

The one that best suits your requirements.  (Or the one provided by a library your code already depends on.)  Beyond that, it is largely a matter of (subjective) preference.

But don't use the "sun.misc" one because it can be changed or withdrawn without any notice.

> Why there's so many choices?

There is nobody out there who has the role of coordinating what goes into 3rd-party libraries.  In the absence of a coordinator, there is scope for duplicated effort and redundant implementations.  That is what has happened here.

If Sun had seen fit to create a public base64 API ... many years ago ... we'd most likely all be using that.  But they didn't.

But it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are there so many Base64 implementations?

Mostly because base64 implementations are not difficult to write, and can easily avoid extra dependencies in your code.  That said, If you are already using a library that can do base64 encoding it makes sense to use the library version.

I have excellent luck with the [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html) libraries for base 64 encoding.  Not only are they concise, fast, and widely used, they are also well tested too.  The API for doing base64 coding and decoding is terse and readable:

```
BaseEncoding.base64().encode("foo");
```

Highly recommended!